# Change CSS only for mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, mobile, web

I just finished creating my website but now I have found a failure. My problem is that my website looks totally nice on the PC. But if I go and look at it from my mobile phone, the spaces between certain images etc. are a great deal too much...

So my question is, how can I create some CSS codes who are only affecting the mobile devices and maybe tablets?

Is there a way?

Comment: you can use `@media` to write css to apply only on some screen resolutions

Comment: Yes. You are looking for [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Answer (score 15):

CSS has feature called [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).
From the MDN link:

> Media queries, added in CSS3, let the presentation of content be tailored to a specific range of output devices without having to change the content itself

For example:

```css
div {
    background: black;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    div {
        background: yellow;
    }
}
```

The background color of this div will be yellow on screen under 1000px width like in the example provided.

Comment: Perhaps `1000`px would be a better width than 600 to differentiate between mobile and desktop devices.

Answer (score 4):

You can use media-queries for different screen resolutions.
Example:

```css
#image img {
    width:375px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
    #image img {width:375px;}
}
```

Comment: This answer would be more helpful (and would score higher) with a little more information.  Could you explain a little further?  Which is which? Any related links?  thanks!  ([answer])

Answer (score 2):

Read and understand about [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

You will be able to adjust the css of certain media sizes of your website.